# Updating TextField throws ComposeNotIdleException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, gui-testing

When calling `AndroidComposeTestRule.performTextInput` on a TextField with initial state, `ComposeNotIdleException` is thrown. Code to replicate the issue:

Production code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val viewModel = MyViewModel()
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                ScreenContent(viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenContent(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "TextField" },
        value = viewModel.textFieldState.value.text,
        onValueChange = { viewModel.updateTextState(it) },
    )
}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _textFieldState = mutableStateOf(TextFieldState())
    val textFieldState = _textFieldState
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _textFieldState.value = _textFieldState.value.copy(text = "initialText")
        }
    }

    fun updateTextState(newText: String) {
        _textFieldState.value = _textFieldState.value.copy(text = newText)
    }
}

data class TextFieldState(
    val text: String = "",
    val showError: Boolean = false,
)
```

Test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()

    @Test
    fun testIdlingTextField() {
        composeRule.setContent { ScreenContent(MyViewModel()) }
        composeRule.onNodeWithContentDescription("TextField").performTextInput("newText")
        composeRule.onNodeWithText("newText").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

The above test passes when I'm just using a simple String instead of `TextFieldState`. I would really appreciate it if someone could give me an explanation of why this is happening.

Comment: Your `ScreenContent` is probably recomposing infinitely. You can put log statements in there to confirm or use the Layout Inspector to observe how your composable is recomposing.

Comment: @Rafsanjani Indeed the `ScreenContent` is recomposing infinitely, but only in the test's `composeRule.setContent`. I was curious about the cause and possible solutions because, after hours of investigation, I didn't find any.

Comment: Mark your `TextFieldState` class with @Stable

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately @Stable doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: For now, I'm calling a LaunchedEffect in the composable to initialize data and it's working fine. Using an initializer in the ViewModel as I did is probably not considered good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the problem further, it turned out that the issue was the initialization of the view model. Just initialize the view model **outside** composeRule's `setContent`:

```
@Test
fun testIdlingTextField() {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()
    composeRule.setContent { ScreenContent(viewModel) }
    composeRule.onNodeWithContentDescription("TextField").performTextInput("newText")
    composeRule.onNodeWithText("newText").assertIsDisplayed()
}
```

*Explanation:* according to the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#:%7E:text=Recomposition%20is%20typically%20triggered%20by%20a%20change%20to%20a%20State%3CT%3E%20object.%20Compose%20tracks%20these%20and%20runs%20all%20composables%20in%20the%20Composition%20that%20read%20that%20particular%20State%3CT%3E), Compose keeps track of state changes by checking which composables read that state. When the view model is created inside the `setContent` composable, it reads `_textFieldState`  (inside the `init` block of `MyViewModel`). So when `performTextInput` changes the `_textFieldState`, the `setContent` gets recomposed and a new view model gets created again, causing the infinite recomposition.

*PS:* Other solutions to solve this problem are:

- inside `init` block of MyViewModel, avoid reading the state: `_textFieldState.value = TextFieldState(text = "initialText")`
- keep the view model initialization inside `setContent` and use the `remember` composable to have the same view model across recompositions